# fixed div moves on Mac when scrolling the page

Tags: css

I have a fixed div on the left side, and only on a Mac, when you downsize the window and scroll to the right for example, the fixed div follows it, but it should stay in place (not show if you scroll).

On windows it's normal.

Any suggestions?

CSS:

```
.header .quick-access {
  background: url("../images/login_search_bg_big.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  top: 165px;
  width: 117px;
}
```

Comment: your code is interpreted correctly in MAC, it SHOULD follow the scroll if `position:fixed;` is used. The problem is somewhere in your Windows OS, i guess your code is wrote incorrectly somewhere, but MAC fix it.

Comment: Yea, I am doing some css fixing on a website and basically half the website is abs / rel positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `position:fixed` with `position:absolute`. You should read more about it as mentioned by @Elad [CSS Positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

`Fixed` means, it will stay at the same position even when you scroll, so your "problem" isn't actually a problem, it does what you coded out there. So it's parent will be your window.

`Absolute` means, that it's parent is the the whole document `html`, and not the windows itself. So you should try this if you want it to be sticked to your html document instead of the window. Do not forget to add a `position:relative` to it's parent tag.

Comment: But why does it stay in place when scrolling right on windows, but not on mac?

Comment: probably there is another issue with your code. to be clear, if you didn't know about positioning, you have probably made another mistakes. If you show us your code, both `css` and `html`, we could answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers interpret tags differently sometimes. 
You may want to simply change your position type to absolute instead of fixed.

Read here for more information:
[Learning CSS positions](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: but then it won't be in the same place always, for example if you scroll down.